# write a python program to fliter a dictionary based on values

Tags: python-3.x

we should write a python program that will filter the dictionary on basis of the values which are multiples of 5. the keys and values of dictionary should be taken as input from the user.

first we should print keys of dictionary then we should print values of the dictionary and then the total dictionary and then the the filtered dictionary where the values are the multiples of 5 should be printed on the next line.
expected output
keys: (input keys)
values: (input values)
total dictionary
filtered dictionary

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where exactly you are facing an issue.

Comment: This question is better for gpt3 than for stacoverflow. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask